# How to get all methods inside a inner class of a class which is present in Jar using ASM java library?

Tags: java, jar, inputstream, java-bytecode-asm, dynamic-class-loaders

I want to get methods inside a inner class.

This is what I have done. I have used JarFile class to get all entries inside a Jar. Now for each entry I have made inputstream and get all methods inside class by using ASM ClassReader class.

Now problem is there are inner classes inside a class. I can get list all inner class nodes, but inner class node doesn't contain information of methods inside it.

To get methods inside inner class there are two ways AFAIK. Make inputstream of inner class and pass it to ClassReader class or give the classname of inner class. In second option it is mandatory for inner class to be loaded. But my Jar is not located in my current classpath so I don't know how to load it.

So can someone please tell me is there a way to make inputstream of inner class or to load classes which are outside of current classpath.

Comment: Since inner classes have class files just like top level classes, they have entries within the jar files, so you are already reading them. All you need to do, is to connect the parsed classes which have an inner class relationship. Usually, a class like `Foo$Bar` is an inner class of `Foo`, but since this is not mandatory (`Foo$Bar` would be a legal class ordinary name too), the inner class attribute of a class will tell you about the true relationships.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load classes into a `ClassReader` with just a `byte[]`, so you just need to read the appropriate `.class` file that represents the inner class (whose name you can obtain in `visitInnerClass` events) and convert it to `byte[]` ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31483645/4047932)).

As an alternative, you can read the bytes and then load it into a `ClassLoader`, then the `ClassReader` will be able to load it from there.